# Pause MDT task sequence to install drivers?

Tags: deployment, imaging, mdt

Is there a good way to pause and resume an MDT deployment task sequence? I need to image some non-standard machines which don't have drivers in our MDT server.

I tried pausing the sequence with `cscript.exe “%SCRIPTROOT%\LTISuspend.wsf”` but it doesn't seem to work, maybe because the machine has no network drivers after booting?`

For the record, here is my environment:

- Windows 7 Pro x64
- Server 2012r2 running MDT

Edit: thanks for your comments. I should have been more clear, that I'm trying to make a hardware agnostic deployment sequence, that will work with any computer and allow me to install drivers manually after booting in to windows. Around 20% of our machines are one-off laptops or custom desktops, so it is not practical to copy drivers for every computer on to the server.

Comment: Have you tried adding the suspend task (not just running the suspend script)?  However if your modifying the task sequence, just add the drivers?

Answer (score 1):

This is what your are looking for.  It will pause the sequence and put an icon on the desktop.  When you are finished doing what ever you need to install, you complete the image by clicking on the desktop icon.

[How to setup LTI-Pause](http://deploymentbunny.com/2011/05/10/ltipause-vbs-take-a-break-in-deployment/)

Answer (score 0):

If the drivers are in exe form then use the `install application` task sequence task. If they are in `inf`/`ini` form then add them to the MDT driver database and use the install driver task.

If you can use a `command prompt` or `powershell` to install them then use the command prompt command or powershell command task.[image: Task sequence items]

Another idea is to include the files for your drivers in your install image and execute the files with the `unattend.xml` after the install is complete so that the network drivers are available for MDT to finish up with.